# Grouping and sorting field values by group in QGIS

Tags: qgis, sql, fields-attributes, sorting, order

I need to sort groups of `"Field A"` by `"Field B"` and write the Sort Order to `"Field C"`. All entities of "X" value in `"Field A"` are ordered amongst themselves by Values in `"Field B"` with that Order in `"Field C"`.

I tried three solutions and a plugin but the result was a sort of the entire dataset and not a sort of the subset.

[image]

Comment: Does the new image help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This SQL query should do what you're asking:

```sql
select
    fieldA, fieldB, row_number() over(partition by fieldA order by fieldB) as fieldC
from
    "your_table"
order by
    fieldA, fieldB;
```

Comment: That seems to have done it, thanks!